# Reported speech formation

Tags: word-usage

Direct speech: He said to her,"I help you because you are a good girl."
 While forming the reported speech for the given sentence shall we write " ... because she **was** a good girl" or "....because she **is** a good girl" ? for her attribute of being good must still be with her. Please do help with your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MyGrammarLab Intermediate (Pearson), we can choose not to change the tense of verbs in reported speech when the **situation** or **feelings**/**opinions** in the original speech are still true. 
For example,

1. My 3 sisters **have** bright red hair (he told me his 3 sisters **have** bright red hair).
2. I really **like** your friend (she said she really **likes** you).

Therefore, you can say *"he said he helped her because she is a good girl"*.